# Does Christian Bale die at the end of Equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

I would like to know if Christian Bale's character dies at the end of the movie Equilibrium (2002). I try to remember desperately, I remember the fight, some big explosion, but then...???

Comment: Of course. Replicants were designed with a finite lifespan.

Comment: Haha - Is he killed or does he die because of his old age?

Comment: According to the wikipedia article on the movie, he is definitely alive at the end

Comment: Christian Bale doesn't, but his character might.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, in the final scene you see him smile (for the first time in the movie, of course) and there's pretty much nobody left to kill him :)

Comment: Ah Yes! I remember, he is with his son and he looks to the sun, right? :D THANKS!!!

Comment: @Bibi541 - No, that happened much earlier in the film

Answer (score 5):

At the very end of the film, just before the credits roll, you see the prozium factories exploding and our **(very much alive)** hero smirking as he surveys his handiwork.

As to his *further survival*, the [original draft script](http://www.equilibriumfans.com/downloads/Equilibrium_Shooting_Script.pdf) was rather more explicit.

> 143 EXT. TERRACE - DAY
>
> She helps Preston out onto the windswept terrace that overlooks
>   Libria. The city stretching into the horizon.
>
> They look out over its vast panorama.
>
> All across Libria, FIREBALLS begin rising up into the sky as, one
>   after another, the EQUIUM FACTORIES explode.
>
> Preston turns to Mary. She to him.
>
> In the light of the explosions, they kiss.
>
> THE END